# Problema ao remover elementos com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando remover campos de um formulário que estão dentro de um `for`. O problema é que apenas o primeiro elemento do for é removido, os demais não funcionam.

Penso que talvez tenha feito alguma coisa errada na função, não tenho experiência com jQuery. Segue o código abaixo:

**O HTML:**

```
<div id="dados">    
   @for($i=0; $i<3;$i++)
      <span>    
         <input type="text" name="op1">
         <a href="#" id="remover">Remover</a>
      </span>    
   @endfor    
</div>
```

**O JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#remover').click(function(){
       $(this).parents('span').remove();
       return false;
    });
)};
```

Comment: id é seletor único, se você deseja criar vários itens utilize um identificador como classe para fazer. você esta removendo apenas o primeiro por que no click voce usa this, removendo apenas o parente span do item clicado, e não todos.

Comment: Mas não quero remover todos não, quero remover um  só. O for irá gerar 3 elementos. Cada elemento vai ter um botão remover. Quando clicar no botão remover quero que seja removido o campo correspondente. O problema é que só o botão do primeiro campo funciona e os demais não.

Comment: Funcionou como eu queria trocando o `id` por `class`! Obrigada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu problema é exatamente no seletor, que utiliza um identificador unico, utilize classes que irá funcionar.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var div = '<span><input type="text" name="op1"><a href="#" class="remover">Remover</a></span>';

var conteudo = $("#conteudo");

conteudo.append(div);
conteudo.append(div);
conteudo.append(div);

$(".remover").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('span').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que estás a usar IDs multiplas. Dentro do ciclo for estás a usar *N* vezes `<a href="#" id="remover">Remover</a>` com a mesma ID e isso é HTML inválido.

Tens de usar classes, por exemplo:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="remover">Remover</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.remover').click(function(){
```

Ou usar assim, sem IDs:

```
$('#dados a').click(function(){
```

E depois podes usar o `.closest('span')`, em ambos os casos, uma vez que queres só remover esse bloco onde houve um click.

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim, que deve resolver.
Segue o [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/y8edn4m4/) com isso funcionando.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.remover').bind('click',function(){  
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Não resolveu. Se eu tiro  o `span` de dentro do `parent` todo o conteúdo da página é removido.

Comment: veja o fiddler que fiz para vc

Comment: Obrigada. Mas o problema foi resolvido apenas trocando `id` por `class`